# Issues with Jquery ajax call

Tags: json, jquery-ui, jquery, user-controls

I'm using jqueryui dialog box to show some details to the user and pass to the codebehind of `usercontrol` in order to perfrom CRUD operations. However, I'm not having success. Can anyone assist me with where I'm getting it wrong? Below is the complete code:

```
 <script>
  $(function() {
    // a workaround for a flaw in the demo system (http://dev.jqueryui.com/ticket/4375), ignore!
    $( "#dialog:ui-dialog" ).dialog( "destroy" );

    var name = $( "#name" ),
      email = $( "#email" ),
      selectedVal= $('#DropDownList1').val();
      allFields = $( [] ).add( name ).add( email ).add( selectedVal ),
      tips = $( ".validateTips" );

    function updateTips( t ) {
      tips
        .text( t )
        .addClass( "ui-state-highlight" );
      setTimeout(function() {
        tips.removeClass( "ui-state-highlight", 1500 );
      }, 500 );
    }

    function checkLength( o, n, min, max ) {
      if ( o.val().length > max || o.val().length < min ) {
        o.addClass( "ui-state-error" );
        updateTips( "Length of " + n + " must be between " +
          min + " and " + max + "." );
        return false;
      } else {
        return true;
      }
    }

    function checkRegexp( o, regexp, n ) {
      if ( !( regexp.test( o.val() ) ) ) {
        o.addClass( "ui-state-error" );
        updateTips( n );
        return false;
      } else {
        return true;
      }
    }

    $( "#dialog-form" ).dialog({
      autoOpen: false,
      height: 310,
      width: 310,
      modal: true,
      buttons: {
        "Login": function() {
          var bValid = true;
          allFields.removeClass( "ui-state-error" );

          bValid = bValid && checkLength( name, "username", 1, 16 );
         bValid = bValid && checkLength( email, "email", 6, 80 );
           bValid = bValid && checkRegexp( email, /^((([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+(\.([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+)*)|((\x22)((((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(([\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f]|\x21|[\x23-\x5b]|[\x5d-\x7e]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(\\([\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0d-\x7f]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]))))*(((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(\x22)))@((([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.)+(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.?$/i, "eg. ui@jquery.com" );


          if ( bValid ) {
             //do ajax post , pass the login details and display  details.aspx page

             $.ajax({
                url: '/GroupSchemeLogin.ascx/insertLoginDetails'
                type: 'POST',
                // serialize the full name , email , selected list
                data: $('#dialog-form').serialize(), //"{no:" + selectedVal + "}", 
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",       
                success: function(response) {
                            if (response.d != "") {
                                alert(response.d);

                            }
                        }


                    });



            $( this ).dialog( "close" );
          }
        },
        Cancel: function() {
          $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        }
      },
      close: function() {
        allFields.val( "" ).removeClass( "ui-state-error" );
      }
    });

    $( "#login" )
      .click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();

        $( "#dialog-form" ).dialog( "open" );
      });
  });
  </script>




  <div id="dialog-form" title="Login to Portfolio"
  <p class="validateTips">All fields are required.</p>

  <form>
  <fieldset>
    <label for="name">Username</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" />
   <label for="email">Email</label>
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" />
     <select id="DropDownList1">
     <option value="product1">Camera</option>
     <option value="product2">DVD</option> 
     <option value="product3">LCD</option> 
 </select> 
  </fieldset>
  </form>
</div>


<a href="#" id="login"><img src="/images/login.jpg" alt="b2bLogin" /></a>
```

Code-behind ascx:

```
[WebMethod]
    public static string insertLoginDetails(string name, string email , string selection)
    {
       //do Calculation
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: its not goin to the method called

Answer (score 1):

You have an unclosed div tag:

```
<div id="dialog-form" title="Login to Portfolio"
```

Answer (score 0):

You are sending the ajax request to an user-control(.ascx). Generally in ASP.NET Web Form application, you can not send Ajax request to an user-control, this would cause to throw an Http exception (403 Forbidden) from server.

```
//.....
$.ajax({
                url: '/GroupSchemeLogin.ascx/insertLoginDetails'
                type: 'POST',
                // serialize the full name , email , selected list
//.....
```

You may move the user-contror (or the `insertLoginDetails` WebMethod) in a .aspx page. You may also use a generic handler to render the content of the user control.